# How to control when appearing element on display?

Tags: javascript, html, constants

I'm trying to make a little quiz game about Formula 1 drivers career. The users will see the drivers first team and the period, then the user guesses who the driver could be depending on the team and the period. If he guesses right then all teams(career) are displayed and the game is over(User wins). However if the user guesses wrong then the next team shows that the driver has in their career and so on. If the user can't guess on the drivers last team the game ends(User looses). It should say 'Guess x of x' on the input container so the user can see how many guesses are left. Instead of having 'Submit' button the user could 'Enter' on the keyboard.

```js
// Define the list of drivers with their respective career paths
const drivers = [{
    name: "Sebastian Vettel",
    career: [{
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2009-2014"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2015-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Aston Martin",
        years: "2021-2022"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Lewis Hamilton",
    career: [{
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2007-2012"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2013-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Max Verstappen",
    career: [{
        team: "Toro Rosso",
        years: "2015"
      },
      {
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2016-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Michael Schumacher",
    career: [{
        team: "Jordan",
        years: "1991"
      },
      {
        team: "Benetton",
        years: "1991-1995"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "1996-2006"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2010-2012"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Alain Prost",
    career: [{
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1980"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "1981-1983"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1984-1989"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "1990-1991"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1993"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Pierre Gasly",
    career: [{
        team: "Torro Rosso",
        years: "2017-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Toro Rosso",
        years: "2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Alphatauri",
        years: "2020-2022"
      },
      {
        team: "Alpine",
        years: "2023-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Mikka Hakkinen",
    career: [{
        team: "Lotus",
        years: "1991-1992"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1993-2001"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Nico Hulkenberg",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2010"
      },
      {
        team: "Force India",
        years: "2011-2012"
      },
      {
        team: "Sauber",
        years: "2013"
      },
      {
        team: "Force India",
        years: "2014-2016"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2017-2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Racing Point",
        years: "2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Aston Martin",
        years: "2021-2022"
      },
      {
        team: "Haas",
        years: "2023-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Robert Kubica",
    career: [{
        team: "BMW Sauber",
        years: "2006-2009"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2010-2011"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2018-2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Alfa Romeo",
        years: "2020-2022"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Niki Lauda",
    career: [{
        team: "Ford Cosworth",
        years: "1971-1972"
      },
      {
        team: "BRM",
        years: "1973"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "1974-1977"
      },
      {
        team: "Alfa Romeo",
        years: "1978-79"
      },
      {
        team: "Ford Cosworth",
        years: "1982-1983"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1983-1985"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Charles Leclerc",
    career: [{
        team: "Sauber",
        years: "2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2019-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Kevin Magnussen",
    career: [{
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2014-2015"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2016"
      },
      {
        team: "Haas",
        years: "2017-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Haas",
        years: "2022-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Nigel Mansell",
    career: [{
        team: "Lotus",
        years: "1980-1984"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1985-1988"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "1989-1990"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1991-1992"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1994"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1995"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Esteban Ocon",
    career: [{
        team: "Manor",
        years: "2016"
      },
      {
        team: "Force India",
        years: "2017-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Alpine",
        years: "2021-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sergio Perez",
    career: [{
        team: "Sauber",
        years: "2011-2012"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2013"
      },
      {
        team: "Force India",
        years: "2014-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Racing Point",
        years: "2018-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2021-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Kimi Raikkonen",
    career: [{
        team: "Sauber",
        years: "2001"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2002-2006"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2007-2009"
      },
      {
        team: "Lotus",
        years: "2012-2013"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2014-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Alfa Romeo",
        years: "2019-2021"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Nico Rosberg",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2005-2009"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2010-2016"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Carlos Sainz",
    career: [{
        team: "Toro Rosso",
        years: "2015-2017"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2017-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2019-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2021-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Ayrton Senna",
    career: [{
        team: "Toleman",
        years: "1984"
      },
      {
        team: "Lotus",
        years: "1985-1987"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1988-1993"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1994"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Lance Stroll",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2017-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Racing Point",
        years: "2019-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Aston Martin",
        years: "2021-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Valtteri Bottas",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2013-2016"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2017-2021"
      },
      {
        team: "Alfa Romeo",
        years: "2022-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Alexander Albon",
    career: [{
        team: "Toro Rosso",
        years: "2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2019-2021"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2022-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Lando Norris",
    career: [{
      team: "McLaren",
      years: "2019-"
    }, ]
  },
  {
    name: "Jenson Button",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2000"
      },
      {
        team: "Benetton",
        years: "2001"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2002"
      },
      {
        team: "Bar",
        years: "2003-2005"
      },
      {
        team: "Honda",
        years: "2006-2008"
      },
      {
        team: "Brawn GP",
        years: "2009"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2010-2017"
      },
    ]
  },
];

// Get the elements from the HTML document
const form = document.querySelector("#guess_driver_path");
const guessInput = form.querySelector("#guess");

// Generate a random driver for the user to guess
let currentDriverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drivers.length);
let currentDriver = drivers[currentDriverIndex];

// Update the HTML document with the current driver's career path
const careerList = document.createElement("ul");
currentDriver.career.forEach(career => {
  const careerItem = document.createElement("li");
  careerItem.textContent = `${career.team} (${career.years})`;
  careerList.appendChild(careerItem);
});
form.querySelector(".career").appendChild(careerList);

// Handle the user's guess
form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const guess = guessInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  const fullName = currentDriver.name.split(" ");
  const firstName = fullName[0].toLowerCase();
  const lastName = fullName[1].toLowerCase();

  if (guess === firstName || guess === lastName) {
    alert(`That's correct! The driver is ${currentDriver.name}`);
  } else {
    alert(`Sorry, that's not correct. Keep guessing!`);
  }

  // Reset the form and generate a new driver for the user to guess
  form.reset();
  currentDriverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drivers.length);
  currentDriver = drivers[currentDriverIndex];

  // Remove the previous driver's career path and update the HTML document with the new one
  careerList.remove();
  careerList.innerHTML = "";
  currentDriver.career.forEach(career => {
    const careerItem = document.createElement("li");
    careerItem.textContent = `${career.team} (${career.years})`;
    careerList.appendChild(careerItem);
  });
  form.querySelector(".career").appendChild(careerList);
});
```

```css
.home {
  color: white;
  /* Change the color to black */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove the underline */
}


/*body {
            background-image: url("/Users/kristjanjakobasgrimsson/Desktop/F1/templates/static/background.png");
        }*/

.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.career {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.guess[type="text"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  resize: none;
}

.guess {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.guess {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1><a class="home" href="home.html">Formula1</a></h1>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Guess the drivers career</h1>
    <form id="guess_driver_path">
      <div class="career">
        Drivers Career
      </div>
      <div class="gues">
        <label for="guess">Guess the driver:</label>
        <textarea id="guess" name="guess" rows="1" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? I don't see any code which you described in the post.

Comment: The code above picks random driver and displays their career and then the user can guess which driver it is. [link(]https://codepen.io/BobbyJackson19/pen/XWPwvLg)

Comment: I was referring to other part after the player wins or lose

Comment: It's quite simple use a counter variable and initialize it with 3 and keep decremeting it's value when user submits a wrong guess. when counter value become zero then don't allows user to enter any input and ask for restart.

Comment: And value of counter will show number of guesses left

Comment: I have decided yet what I want after the player wins but temporarily it just restarts the game. After the player gets wrong answer then the next team and periods displays and so on. If the driver has only driver for 3 teams then the players has 3 guesses and if he doesn't guess right at guess nr.3 then the player looses. I have it temporarily if the players looses the game restarts, havent decided yet what happens. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal can you make an answer for me? :)

Comment: please explain in simple manner what is your target?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal I'll try to explain it shortly: The users will see the drivers first team and the period, then the user guesses who the driver could be depending on the team and the period. If he guesses right then all teams(career) are displayed and the game is over(User wins). However if the user guesses wrong then the next team shows that the driver has in their career and so on. If the user can't guess on the drivers last team the game ends(User looses). It should say 'Guess x of x' on the input container so the user can see how many guesses are left. Its hard to explain shortly.

Comment: I got your point you want to show the how many guesses each player have left and when some wins you want to display all players with their careers?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal when player wins(Guesses right driver) then the drivers career is displayed. If the right driver is Hamilton and the first clue(team and period) is McLaren 2007-2012 and the player guesses 'Hamilton' then his career should be displayed. McLaren 2007-2012                                                               Mercedes 2013-

Comment: got it preparing your answer hold on...

Answer (score 0):

**Paste the JS code shown below**. When someone guesses the correct driver then there is a function which is **displayDriverCareer** called.This function definition is empty because I have left it for you. Other than that you can try It's working with no guesses left concept. I'm using **counter** to track incorrect attempts.

```js
// Define the list of drivers with their respective career paths
const drivers = [{
    name: "Sebastian Vettel",
    career: [{
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2009-2014"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2015-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Aston Martin",
        years: "2021-2022"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Lewis Hamilton",
    career: [{
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2007-2012"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2013-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Max Verstappen",
    career: [{
        team: "Toro Rosso",
        years: "2015"
      },
      {
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2016-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Michael Schumacher",
    career: [{
        team: "Jordan",
        years: "1991"
      },
      {
        team: "Benetton",
        years: "1991-1995"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "1996-2006"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2010-2012"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Alain Prost",
    career: [{
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1980"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "1981-1983"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1984-1989"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "1990-1991"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1993"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Pierre Gasly",
    career: [{
        team: "Torro Rosso",
        years: "2017-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Toro Rosso",
        years: "2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Alphatauri",
        years: "2020-2022"
      },
      {
        team: "Alpine",
        years: "2023-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Mikka Hakkinen",
    career: [{
        team: "Lotus",
        years: "1991-1992"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1993-2001"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Nico Hulkenberg",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2010"
      },
      {
        team: "Force India",
        years: "2011-2012"
      },
      {
        team: "Sauber",
        years: "2013"
      },
      {
        team: "Force India",
        years: "2014-2016"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2017-2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Racing Point",
        years: "2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Aston Martin",
        years: "2021-2022"
      },
      {
        team: "Haas",
        years: "2023-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Robert Kubica",
    career: [{
        team: "BMW Sauber",
        years: "2006-2009"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2010-2011"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2018-2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Alfa Romeo",
        years: "2020-2022"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Niki Lauda",
    career: [{
        team: "Ford Cosworth",
        years: "1971-1972"
      },
      {
        team: "BRM",
        years: "1973"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "1974-1977"
      },
      {
        team: "Alfa Romeo",
        years: "1978-79"
      },
      {
        team: "Ford Cosworth",
        years: "1982-1983"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1983-1985"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Charles Leclerc",
    career: [{
        team: "Sauber",
        years: "2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2019-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Kevin Magnussen",
    career: [{
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2014-2015"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2016"
      },
      {
        team: "Haas",
        years: "2017-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Haas",
        years: "2022-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Nigel Mansell",
    career: [{
        team: "Lotus",
        years: "1980-1984"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1985-1988"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "1989-1990"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1991-1992"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1994"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1995"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Esteban Ocon",
    career: [{
        team: "Manor",
        years: "2016"
      },
      {
        team: "Force India",
        years: "2017-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Alpine",
        years: "2021-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sergio Perez",
    career: [{
        team: "Sauber",
        years: "2011-2012"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2013"
      },
      {
        team: "Force India",
        years: "2014-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Racing Point",
        years: "2018-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2021-"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Kimi Raikkonen",
    career: [{
        team: "Sauber",
        years: "2001"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2002-2006"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2007-2009"
      },
      {
        team: "Lotus",
        years: "2012-2013"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2014-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Alfa Romeo",
        years: "2019-2021"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Nico Rosberg",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2005-2009"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2010-2016"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Carlos Sainz",
    career: [{
        team: "Toro Rosso",
        years: "2015-2017"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2017-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2019-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Ferrari",
        years: "2021-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Ayrton Senna",
    career: [{
        team: "Toleman",
        years: "1984"
      },
      {
        team: "Lotus",
        years: "1985-1987"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "1988-1993"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "1994"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Lance Stroll",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2017-2018"
      },
      {
        team: "Racing Point",
        years: "2019-2020"
      },
      {
        team: "Aston Martin",
        years: "2021-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Valtteri Bottas",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2013-2016"
      },
      {
        team: "Mercedes",
        years: "2017-2021"
      },
      {
        team: "Alfa Romeo",
        years: "2022-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Alexander Albon",
    career: [{
        team: "Toro Rosso",
        years: "2019"
      },
      {
        team: "Red Bull",
        years: "2019-2021"
      },
      {
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2022-"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Lando Norris",
    career: [{
      team: "McLaren",
      years: "2019-"
    }, ]
  },
  {
    name: "Jenson Button",
    career: [{
        team: "Williams",
        years: "2000"
      },
      {
        team: "Benetton",
        years: "2001"
      },
      {
        team: "Renault",
        years: "2002"
      },
      {
        team: "Bar",
        years: "2003-2005"
      },
      {
        team: "Honda",
        years: "2006-2008"
      },
      {
        team: "Brawn GP",
        years: "2009"
      },
      {
        team: "McLaren",
        years: "2010-2017"
      },
    ]
  },
];



// Get the elements from the HTML document
const form = document.querySelector("#guess_driver_path");
const guessInput = form.querySelector("#guess");
let counter =3; 

// Generate a random driver for the user to guess
let currentDriverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drivers.length);
let currentDriver = drivers[currentDriverIndex];

// Update the HTML document with the current driver's career path
const careerList = document.createElement("ul");
currentDriver.career.forEach(career => {
  const careerItem = document.createElement("li");
  careerItem.textContent = `${career.team} (${career.years})`;
  careerList.appendChild(careerItem);
});
form.querySelector(".career").appendChild(careerList);

// Handle the user's guess


// function to guess again or restart the game
const guessAgain =()=>{
    form.reset();
    currentDriverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drivers.length);
    currentDriver = drivers[currentDriverIndex];
  
    // Remove the previous driver's career path and update the HTML document with the new one
    careerList.remove();
    careerList.innerHTML = "";
    currentDriver.career.forEach(career => {
      const careerItem = document.createElement("li");
      careerItem.textContent = `${career.team} (${career.years})`;
      careerList.appendChild(careerItem);
    });
    form.querySelector(".career").appendChild(careerList);
}

//display the driver's career function
const displayDriverCareer = (currentDriver) => {
   // show your driver data on screen and give a reset button.
}
form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const guess = guessInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  const fullName = currentDriver.name.split(" ");
  const firstName = fullName[0].toLowerCase();
  const lastName = fullName[1].toLowerCase();

  if (guess === firstName || guess === lastName) {
    alert(`That's correct! The driver is ${currentDriver.name}`);
    counter=3;
    displayDriverCareer(currentDriver);
  } else {
    counter--;
    if(counter>0){
     alert(`Sorry, that's not correct. ${counter} guess left!`);
    }
    if(counter === 0){
        counter=3;
        alert("Game Over! click ok to restart the game");
    }
    guessAgain();
  }

 

  // Reset the form and generate a new driver for the user to guess
});
```

Comment: I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok but this code is similar to mine,but I was asking for how can I make this possible: The users will see the drivers first team and the period, then the user guesses who the driver could be depending on the team and the period. If he guesses right then all teams(career) are displayed and the game is over(User wins). However if the user guesses wrong then the next team shows that the driver has in their career and so on. If the user can't guess on the drivers last team the game ends(User looses). It should say 'Guess x of x' on the input container so the user can see how many guesses are left.

Comment: `Guess the driver for this career path:
Team                       Years
McLaren                2007-2012
(The user guesses)Guess: Verstappen

Team                       Years
McLaren                2007-2012
Mercedes                  2013-
(The user guesses)Guess: Hamilton
That's correct! The driver is Lewis Hamilton!`

Comment: Now I definitely got your query. You will first show a team in a driver's career, if users guesses wrong then you will show the other team in the same driver's career. If the user guess right then you will display all the team of the driver's career.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Hey What if a driver has only two teams or one in his career, in that case we can only give one or two guess to the player?

Comment: Yes that is okay, if driver has only driver for one team then the user has one guess. I want to make a tracker or something that shows the user how many guess the user has and has already guessed.